# Skip void arguments

Tags: c++, arguments, c++14, void, template-specialization

I'm trying to call a function with the correct number of parameters in C++14. I have a template class that defines an alias of the itself or void, based on template filters : either the argument is skipped, or passed, something like this :

```cpp
template<typename comp>
struct exclude {};

template<typename comp>
struct shouldPassComponent
{
    using type = comp;
    
    comp& operator()(comp* component) { return *component; }
    const comp& operator()(const comp* component) const { return *component; }
}

// void is aliased instead of the component
template<typename comp>
struct shouldPassComponent<exclude<comp>>
{
    using type = void;

    void operator()(comp* component) {}
    void operator()(const comp* component) const {}
}

// if void, the argument should be skipped/not evaluated instead
std::invoke(func, shouldPassComponent<types>()(comps)...); // error here
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work because the compiler still evaluates "void()" in arguments (error: "no matching overloaded function found").

So I tried the non-template way to see if it would work :

```cpp
void CallFunction();

CallFunction(void()); // error here
```

However, the compiler errors with : "error C2672: CallFunction: no matching overloaded function found". So I thought about the fact that lambda accepts auto arguments :

```cpp
void CallFunction();

auto lambdaTest = [](auto... Arguments)
{
    //....
    CallFunction(Arguments...);
};

lambdaTest(void()); // error here
```

Still, the compiler errors with : "error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found" when calling lambdaTest. I searched for hours on Internet, and now I'm out of luck.

Is there any way to prevent evaluating/discarding some arguments from a variadic to be passed? Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the first approach? If you add semicolons after class definitions this code works: `int i = 5;
    shouldPassComponent<int> spc1;
    spc1((int*) &i);
    shouldPassComponent<exclude<int>> spc2;
    spc2((int*) &i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36818808/9142528 it's based on an index sequence which I never thought about. It feeds an index sequence based on a predictate (for each type, puts the index of the type if the predicate for this type has a value of true, nothing otherwise).

```cpp
template<typename component>
struct exclude {};

template<typename component>
struct isResolvable
{
    enum { value = true };
};

template<typename component>
struct isResolvable<exclude<component>>
{
    enum { value = false };
};

template<typename...components>
struct view_t
{
    template<typename component>
    struct component_t
    {
        using type = component;
    };

    template<typename component>
    struct component_t<exclude<component>>
    {
        using type = component;
    };

    template<typename funcType>
    static void call(funcType func, typename component_t<components>::type&... comps)
    {
        callImpl(func, std::make_tuple((&comps)...), find_indices<isResolvable, components...>{});
    }

    template<typename funcType, typename...components, size_t...Is>
    static void callImpl(funcType func, const std::tuple<components*...>& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        std::invoke(func, *std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
    }
};

struct test1 {};
struct test2 {};

void testCallback(test1& comp)
{
}

void test()
{
    test1 comp1;
    test2 comp2;

    view_t<test1, exclude<test2>>::call(&testCallback, comp1, comp2);
}
```